# Uploadify not uploading after ~25MB

Tags: jquery, file-upload, uploadify

I'm using Uploadify on localhost to develop a site where users can upload files. Everything so far is working fine, but Uploadify refuses to upload any file that's over ~25MB.

I'm using this function to report upload status:

```
function updateProgress(file, bytesUploaded, bytesTotal, totalBytesUploaded, totalBytesTotal) {
    var percent = totalBytesUploaded / totalBytesTotal * 100;
    $('.bar').css('width', percent + '%');
    console.log(percent +' ' + bytesUploaded);
}
```

If I try uploading any file that's under 25MB in size it works fine, any file above that and the upload just stops. No error or anything.

These are my relevant `php.ini` settings:

```
post_max_size = 1024M
upload_max_filesize = 1000M
memory_limit = 1024M
```

and I've confirmed they are correct using `phpinfo()`. This is my upload script:

```
<?php
$targetFolder = '/uploads'; // Relative to the root

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
    $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
    echo '1';
}
?>
```

Is there something that I've missed here? Perhaps an Apache configuration setting? The Uploadify documentation has been less than helpful on this error, and I can't seem to find anything through Google.

Thanks.

Comment: What's your `max_execution_time`?

Comment: 30 seconds, but seen as the site is on localhost and it's essentially just copying the file no upload ever goes past that. In fact it stops uploading in under a second after the upload starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. I had the jQuery effect `fadeOut` being applied to the form which at the end of the animation sets the forms style to `display: none`. When the form gets to this Uploadify stops the upload.

I simply did this instead:

```
$('#upload-form').animate({opacity: 0}, function() {
    /// whatever
}
```